# Android: How to center a LinearLayout between the screen and a button in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have the following XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/login_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/login_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/forgot_pass"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:text="@string/login_button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see I have a button that's on the bottom of my screen, but I want to centralize the LinearLayout between the top of the screen and the button, not the top of the screen with the bottom of the screen.

I've already tried `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` but it isn't what I want.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code, and your linearlayout will be center aligned between top and bottom button

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/login_btn"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/login_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/login_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/forgot_pass"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:text="@string/login_button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. @cricket_007 told me to do the exact same thing, and it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Right now, it's centered relative to the parent element. If you want to center between the button and the top, you need another RelativeLayout that surrounds the LinearLayout with the button outside and make that match the parent boundaries. Then you center the LinearLayout in that. You might as well just make the outer element a LinearLayout.

Or you can also use a FrameLayout with center gravity around the inner LinearLayout

Or, ConstraintLayout might be even better

Comment: I tried to use a ConstraintLayout but I couldn't put the button on the bottom of the screen. I searched it but I couldn't find anything. So I just used RelativeLayout.
I'll try to do what you said: surround the Layout and 'll see if it worked

Comment: You just anchor the button to the  bottom, as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to add another relative layout for that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/login_btn"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/login_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/login_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/forgot_pass"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-5dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:text="@string/login_button"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Try this I hope this is what you are looking for?
your linear layout is covering all the area from the top of your screen till the top of the button.

[image]

Comment: Actually no, I don't want that. I want the LinearLayout to be centered between the top of the screen to the top of the button

Comment: I don't want it either. I was looking to a possibility that allowed me to center the LinearLayout between the top of the screen and the top of the button, not on the middle of the screen